# Can I write Lua script to request data from http API?

Tags: lua, jailbreak, cydia, autotouch

Here is the demo code I learn from other poster:

```
-- test.lua 
function get(url) 
    local handle = io.popen("curl -q -k -s -m l"..url) 
    local result = handle:read("*a") 
    handle:close() 
    return result 
end

local result = get("http://headers.jsontest.com/");

alert(result);
```

I install cUrl in my Cydia iPhone6. When I run this test.lua on AutoTouch, it has no error log, but didn't print anything...

1. How can I make a success http request by Lua?
2. How to encode and decode for loop the response JSON data?
3. Can I print() the output? or I only can use log() and alert() on iphone to debug lua script?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that io.popen is allowed? Some applications disable it for security reasons.

Comment: @Freakyy Where I can find the setting config on my iphone ios? If it is not allow to do it, which alternative way that I can use lua to request http api?

Comment: I am not familiar with Cydia. There isn't a built-in Lua API which provides networking functionality. You'd have to research if the program offers any libraries.

Comment: @Freakyy Thanks for your reply, because AutoTouch is a app on Cydia platform in JB iphone. AutoTouch allow user write lua script to control/simulate the touch event on iphone. But their doc didn't talk about how to use lua on autoTouch to request API. So I am finding a way to extend the ability of their Lua script.

Comment: `"curl -q -k -s -m l"..url` doesn't seem right. You probably need a space at the end of the string and perhaps `-m l` should be `-m 1`.